# winappdeploycmd error: Windows cannot install app data for package because it is already installed

Tags: windows-10, uwp, sideloading

I **sideloaded a uwp app to my Win 10 Mobile Lumia 640**.  Later I went to update it and I got an error (see below).  I uninstalled the app from my phone by the long click/uninstall method.  I tried again (and several more times) but I keep getting the following error...

**----------------------------------------**

Checking for dependencies...
Scanning given package for all necessary dependencies...

Attempting to match dependency: 'Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00'
Dependency found at 'D:\ProgDev\VS2015\Projects\BwMinWin10\BwMinWin10\AppPackages\BwMinWin10_1.0.4.0_Test\Dependencies\ARM\Microsoft.VCLibs.ARM.14.00.appx'.

Attempting to match dependency: 'Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.1'
Dependency found at 'D:\ProgDev\VS2015\Projects\BwMinWin10\BwMinWin10\AppPackages\BwMinWin10_1.0.4.0_Test\Dependencies\ARM\Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.1.appx'.

Sending 'BwMinWin10_1.0.4.0_x86_x64_arm.appxbundle' to the remote device.

Sending dependency 'Microsoft.VCLibs.ARM.14.00.appx' to the remote device.

Sending dependency 'Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.1.appx' to the remote device.

Installing app...

Remote action failed. 0x80073CF9

**Windows cannot install app data for package Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.22929.0_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe to volume D: because it is already installed to volume C:.**

0x80073cf9
Cleaning up dependencies.
Cleaning up app package.
Cleaning up remote target components.
Disconnecting.
Done.

**-----------------------------------------------------**

Looks like an issue with the Dependency: 'Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00', which surprises me.  I am assuming the internal ram is drive C: and the SD Card is drive D:.

Does anyone have solution to this error?

**Begin Edit**

Followed the documentation on this page...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-s/library/windows/desktop/hh454036.aspx
    ...under the **Sideload your app package** section it has the following sentence....  *To install an app to a Windows 10 Mobile device, use the WinAppDeployCmd.exe*

...which takes you too... https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt203806.aspx

This was my command line entry...
**winappdeploycmd install -file "D:\ProgDev\VS2015\Projects\BwMinWin10\BwMinWin10\AppPackages\BwMinWin10_1.0.4.0_Test\BwMinWin10_1.0.4.0_x86_x64_arm.appxbundle" -ip 192.168.0.222 -pin xxxxxx**

This worked the first time I installed it.

I did a *winappdeploycmd list -ip xxxxxxxxxx* but I did not see (or maybe didn't recognize) the program listed so I did an uninstall from the app menu by pressing on the tile and choosing uninstall.

**End Edit**

Comment: Could you detail your steps? How did you sideload the app to the phone, by which tool? How did you update it? If it is installed by WinAppDeployCmd.exe, could you use WinAppDeployCmd to uninstall it?

Answer (score 0):

Below are my suggestions:

1) Which commands do you use to uninstall or update the package? Do you try with winappdeloycmd to uninstall?

2) What happens if you install app on C:?

2)Could you clean the winphone's cache?

3) Which OS version is on your device? Could you please update it to the highest version? Currently there is a latest build for Windows Phones: Build 10536.

Looking forward to your update.

[UPDATE]

I tried on a device and I can reproduce your problem. It seems there is something wrong when depolying to a removable device via WinAppDeployCmd. When I WinappdeployCmd to "phone", everything works fine. However, if I set "install app on SD", I got the same error when updating or reinstalling. I will try to communicate with internal team for this issue. If any update, I will let you know. For now, the work around should be using WinappDeployCmd to install app on "phone"(default "C:"). If you want to debug on SD, you can deploy in Visual Studio.

Comment: whew... so glad you were able to duplicate the error.  I hope this is resolved quickly.

As for installing on C: I don't see the parm to do that via winappdeploycmd so I was just going to settings in the phone and default to installing apps to phone memory (which there isn't a lot of on the lumia 640).

Comment: I have already reported a bug for this. Any update I will notify you here. Please keep tracing this thread.

Comment: will do just to see it resolved, but I have pretty much lost faith in the direction ms is going with universal apps.

Comment: @rdskill any luck with that? or is it still giving errors

Answer (score 0):

geezz.. the format for responding needs a major rethink.   so i'll put this in an answer instead.

1. Uninstalled by the app listing.  long click.  select uninstall.
2. Not much room on the phone drive (c:?)  so phone is set to install all apps to SD card (D:).
3. I can't find how to clear winphone cache.  I assume you mean app cache.  I did find a article talking about a way to clear store app cache using WSReset.exe.
4. Just updated to 10586.11 today.

So I tried again.  Same error.

So then I went and uninstalled *Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.22929.0_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe* which lives on the C: drive using winAppDeployCmd.  This uninstall was successful! yeah!

I then ran the install again I got the same error saying it could not install *Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.22929.0_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe* to the D: drive because it was already on the C: drive.  Boo!

So I am still stuck trying to sideload this app. :-(